How to Prevent Infinite Logging Loop with Tokio-Tracing and Hyper in a Custom Subscriber in Rust?
Note - I have gone through Suppressing external library logs in a tokio tracing subscriber and How to turn off tracing events emitted by other crates?, and they don't answer this question.
Context:
I'm creating a Tokio tracing subscriber that captures logs from tracing instrumented libraries and exports them to a backend service using the hyper crate. However, hyper is also instrumented with Tokio tracing, which causes an infinite logging loop because the logs generated by hyper are captured and exported by my subscriber.
Please note that the application integrating my Subscriber might also use the hyper crate. I only want to suppress tracing events emitted from hyper due to it's usage within my Tokio subscriber's implementation, not from the application's use of hyper. Adding a filter for hyper as suggested in the linked question would suppress all events from hyper, regardless of where it is used. I've provided more details in the example code and problem statement below.
Here’s a simplified version of my code, self-contained and runnable (including the solution I tried to suppress the logs from hyper crate):"
/*
hyper = { version = "0.14.7", features = [ "full" ] }
tokio = { version = "1.33.0", features = ["full"] }
tracing = "0.1.25"
tracing-core = "0.1"
pin-project = "1.1.3"
tracing-subscriber = "0.3.17"
*/

use pin_project::pin_project;
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::{Context, Poll};
use tracing::info;
use tracing::Event;
use tracing::Metadata;
use tracing::Subscriber;
use tracing_core::span::Id;
use tracing_core::span::Record;

// Define a task-local variable for suppression
tokio::task_local! {
    static SUPPRESSED: bool;
}

struct SimpleSubscriber;

impl Subscriber for SimpleSubscriber {
    fn enabled(&self, _metadata: &Metadata<'_>) -> bool {
        !is_logging_suppressed()
    }

    fn new_span(&self, _: &tracing::span::Attributes<'_>) -> Id {
        Id::from_u64(10)
    }

    fn event(&self, event: &Event<'_>) {
        if is_logging_suppressed() {
            return;
        }

        // Extract the required metadata before moving into the async context
        let target = event.metadata().target().to_string();
        let name = event.metadata().name().to_string();
        let level = event.metadata().level().clone();

        let suppressed_future = SUPPRESSED.scope(true, async move {
            // the actual logging event, the hyper tracing event generated here should be suppressed
            hyper_wrapper::make_hyper_call("mock_upload_event", &target, &name, &level).await;
        });

        let suppress_logging_future = SuppressLogging {
            inner: suppressed_future,
        };

        // Use tokio::spawn instead of spawn_local
        tokio::task::spawn(suppress_logging_future);
    }

    fn record(&self, _: &Id, _: &Record<'_>) {}

    fn record_follows_from(&self, _: &Id, _: &Id) {}

    fn enter(&self, _: &Id) {}

    fn exit(&self, _: &Id) {}
}

#[pin_project]
struct SuppressLogging<F> {
    #[pin]
    inner: F,
}

impl<F: Future> Future for SuppressLogging<F> {
    type Output = F::Output;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        let this = self.project();
        this.inner.poll(cx)
    }
}

fn is_logging_suppressed() -> bool {
    SUPPRESSED.try_with(|val| *val).unwrap_or(false)
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let subscriber = SimpleSubscriber;
    tracing::subscriber::set_global_default(subscriber)
        .expect("Setting default subscriber failed.");

    // Make a small Hyper call in the main method
    lib::some_func().await;
}

// Define the module within the same file
mod lib {
    use tracing::info;
    use tracing_core::Level;

    pub async fn some_func() {
        // this should be logged
        info!(name: "this-is-also-logged", "test");

        // the tracing event generated by hyper crate should not be suppressed.
        super::hyper_wrapper::make_hyper_call("main method", "main", "startup", &Level::INFO).await;
    }
}

mod hyper_wrapper {
    use hyper::Client;
    use hyper::Uri;
    use tracing_core::Level;

    pub async fn make_hyper_call(context: &str, target: &str, name: &str, level: &Level) {
        let client = Client::new();
        let uri = "http://www.google.com".parse::<Uri>().unwrap();
        let response = client.get(uri).await;
        match response {
            Ok(_response) => {
                //let _body = hyper::body::to_bytes(response).await.unwrap();
                println!(
                    "{} - [{}] - {} - {} ",
                    context,
                    level,
                    target,
                    name,
                );
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("{} - [{}] - {} - {} - Error: {:?}", context, level, target, name, e);
            }
        }
    }
}


Problem Statement:

I am creating a Tokio tracing subscriber, which gets the logs from the tokio-tracing instrumented libraries, and exports them to some backend service using (say) hyper.
Now the hyper crate is also instrumented with Tokio tracing, which results in the logs from this crate being received by the event() method of my subscriber and getting exported. This results in an infinite logging loop.
While I can create a filter to remove all logs emitted from the hyper crate, this crate might also be used by applications that depend on my crate or by other libraries these applications use. And the application developers might not want logs from their usage of hyper to be filtered out.
So, I want to filter only the logs generated by the hyper crate from within my subscriber implementation.
I tried using tokio::task_local to set the suppression flag within my subscriber, and then use that to decide whether to export the logs or not. However, it seems that task_local won't be propagated across multiple async calls made within the hyper crate.

Question:
What is the best way to achieve this? How can I filter out the logs generated by the hyper crate within my subscriber implementation without affecting the logs generated by the hyper crate in other parts of the application?
Please note that hyper is just one of those crates. My Subscriber would be using other crates like reqwest and tonic and it would be same issue with them.
About the example:

SimpleSubscriber is my subscriber to process the logs generated through tokio-tracing library. This would be published as a crate.
fn main would be part of the application which configures my crate, and also uses the library/module named lib.
Library lib invoke info! macro to do logging, and also uses hyper crate to send some HTTP request for it's purpose. The logs generated through lib module (using info! and internally within hyper should be exported through my subscriber.
Now my subscriber also uses hyper crate through event() -> make_hyper_call, and I don't want the logs generated by hyper usage within my subscriber to be lopped back, and exported. As this will cause an infinite loop.
I tried using tokio::task_local flag named SUPPRESSED, and propagating it to async tasks through the future wrapper SuppressLogging, however the flag is not getting propagated to all the chain of async calls within the hyper crate. So no suppression is happening.


Could you explain why the questions you linked above do not answer your question? Isn't suppressing the tracing events emitted by the hyper crate enough?

I only want to suppress the tracing events emitted by the usage of hyper within the implementation of my Tokio subscriber. I do not want to suppress the tracing events emitted by the usage of hyper by the application that uses my Tokio subscriber. Adding a filter for hyper as suggested in linked question would mean suppressing all events emitted by hyper, regardless of where it is used. I have tried to explain this situation in the problem statement.

I can't think of any solution besides patching hyper or tokio to add an "inherited task local" type. A half-solution will be to disable all logging while you send the logs.

Thanks @ChayimFriedman - yes that is an option. However, hyper may have other async dependencies, and this "inherited task local" may need to be added in all those libraries used in the request chain. Another option I felt was using tokio-current-thread-runtime, to ensure that the async request is created in the current thread, and then using the thread-local for suppression. However, that could have performance issues.
